# Flyway exclude some migrations in Callbacks

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, flyway

I was wondering is there a way to exclude some migrations on runtime, using Flyway's `Callback` methods.

I am already doing some work in them, but I would like to exclude some migrations that contain *dev* in their description.

Thanks!

edit: added my simple change to the migration resolver

```
@Override
public Collection<ResolvedMigration> resolveMigrations() {
    assert flyway != null;
    assert flyway.getLocations() != null;
    assert flyway.getLocations().length > 0;

    List<ResolvedMigration> migrations = Lists.newArrayList();


    for (String stringLocation : flyway.getLocations()) {
        Location location = new Location(stringLocation);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        Resource[] resources = scanner.scanForResources(location,
                flyway.getSqlMigrationPrefix(),
                flyway.getSqlMigrationSuffix());

        for (Resource resource : resources) {
            if (!resource.getFilename().contains("_dev")) {
                ResolvedMigrationImpl resolvedMigration = extractMigrationInfo(location, resource);
                resolvedMigration.setPhysicalLocation(resource.getLocationOnDisk());
                resolvedMigration.setExecutor(new SqlMigrationExecutor(new PostgreSQLDbSupport(flywayConnection),
                        resource,
                        new PlaceholderReplacer(flyway.getPlaceholders(),
                                flyway.getPlaceholderPrefix(),
                                flyway.getPlaceholderSuffix()),
                                flyway.getEncoding()));

                migrations.add(resolvedMigration);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(migrations, new ResolvedMigrationComparator());
    }

    return migrations;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flyway provides a tool(s) to do this already.

First is [`locations`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/migrate) which you could use to silo your development / test migrations.

```
src/main/resources
└── db
    ├── migration       <-- Common migrations here
    └── dev-migration   <-- Dev only migrations here
```

Second is[`resolvers`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/migrate). A bit more heavyweight but can be used to achieve a similar thing.

Personally, I have used the first option to segregate development migrations.

Comment: Hmm, yes I know about that, but apparently when the project was started, we didn't know we could do that, so we ended up using something like `V1_0__dev_test.sql`. Think I'll just have to either refactor, or I'll check out the resolvers, if that can solve it. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I wrote my implementation, it works fine, and doesn't add migrations with `_dev` in their description, but the issue is - it still runs those migrations... Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, it's basically the same as Flyway's, but with the small change - it checks the file description to see should it add it to resolved migrations. Posting it in the OP.